# How do I transpose columns into rows of a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

My current data frame is comprised of 10 rows and thousands of columns. The setup currently looks similar to  this:

```
A   B   A   B
1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8
```

But I desire something more like below, where essentially I would transpose the columns into rows once the headers start repeating themselves.

```
A   B
1   2
5   6
3   4
7   8
```

I've been trying `df.reshape` but perhaps can't get the syntax right. Any suggestions on how best to transpose the data like this?

Comment: So you've got a DF with duplicated column names?

Comment: Yes the column names start repeating themselves

Comment: So are you looking to reset at repeats... or just that everything all 'A's become one columns and all `B`s become a single column etc...?

Comment: Essentially yes I think you hit the nail on the head... All A's should be in one column and all B's should be in one column etc.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably go for stacking, grouping and then building a new DataFrame from scratch, eg:

```
pd.DataFrame({col: vals for col, vals in df.stack().groupby(level=1).agg(list).items()})
```

That'll also give you:

```
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6
3  7  8
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `stack`, `groupby` and `pivot`:

```
stacked = df.T.stack().to_frame().assign(idx=df.T.stack().groupby(level=0).cumcount()).reset_index()
output = stacked.pivot("idx", "level_0", 0).rename_axis(None, axis=1).rename_axis(None, axis=0)

>>> output
   A  B
0  1  2
1  5  6
2  3  4
3  7  8
```